# "Мгновение" имеет связанный корень или свободный?

Tags: словообразование, морфемика

Слово **мгновение** имеет связанный корень или свободный?
Объясните, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не тема свободных и связанных корней.

**Определение**

Корни, которые употребляются лишь в сочетании со словообразовательными морфемами (приставками или суффиксами), называют **связанными**, отличая их от «обычных» — свободных корней, например: во-нз-и-ть, про-нз-и-ть (сравним: во-ткнуть, проткнуть), добав-и-ть, у-бав-и-ть

В слове ***мгновение*** можно выделить **исторический корень МИГ/МГ**, но связанным он не является. Слово не делится на морфемы, так как образование ***мигнуть — мгновение*** не является семантически очевидным.